# The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription key

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, plist

I am getting a crash below:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

But I have already added the 'Privacy - Contacts Usage Description' key

[image]

Comment: Did you try clean and build your project?

Comment: I have this problem now on a fresh project. I didn't get an Info.plist when creating the project and adding it seems to make no difference. Cleaning doesn't either.

Answer (score 6):

Please check your .plist as a source code and see if your key doesn't contain space at the end like:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription </key>
```

Comment: I have this problem on a fresh project. This isn't my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Could be that you have accidentally added the key to your UITests target. I've done that a few times with the location privacy keys.

By the way, your contacts usage description "Allow contact access" probably would not pass Apple's review, because it does not state *why* you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Go To info.plist And

Privacy - Contacts Usage Description

Value : Allow Contact Access For Details

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkzyA.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. There was no Info.plist in a new project and adding it didn't do anything.

Solution:

- Click project
- Select `Info` tab
- HERE you can add stuff!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using App test and and App UItest then there would be multple plist files in your project just make it sure you are adding discription in right if **plist**

[image]